# Post deleted but Not an Answer flag is still pending

Tags: bug, status-norepro, flags, deleted-answers

Not sure if this is somehow related to all the wonkiness going on with the CSS updates recently but a recent deleted post on SFF was deleted (via 3 users) but the flags haven't been marked as helpful and are still pending.

[image: Screenshot showing deleted post with a pending NaA flag in the flag history page]

The post was flagged at 15:10:34 and deleted at 15:14:33.

Comment: Don't know if this is relevant or not, but I deleted by the action button on the post instead of by vote.

Comment: [Link to the post](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/228424/58193) if needed.

Comment: It shouldn't be related to the style changes, but if I'm honest... few things surprise me anymore.

Comment: @AdamLear I meant more, I didn’t know if any JavaScript or backend changes had happened at the same time. But thinking back I think the servers were having some hiccups at that time so it may have been a one off.

Comment: We are definitely seeing this on Stack Overflow, sporadically deletion (from the flag dashboard or otherwise) leads to a deleted post with the flag still active.

Answer (score 4):

This appears to have been a temporary issue that occurred between March 7 and March 11 of this year.  There aren't any obvious culprits in the code repo so maybe something weird happened in the database?

I'm showing that 47 answers were affected on SO at that time, and typically zero or 1 on other sites I checked.

Comment: On a related note, I thoroughly enjoyed the linked post. Go Nog!